# Back button not working in JavaScript carousel

Tags: javascript, carousel

I'm a beginner working on a carousel using JavaScript and I have a back button that is not working when I click on it. Here is the JavaScript code that I'm using to handle the click on the button:

```js
var slidesTab = [
  document.getElementById("slide-1"),
  document.getElementById("slide-2"),
  document.getElementById("slide-3")
];

var nextBtn = document.getElementById("next");
var prevBtn = document.getElementById("previous");

var currentSlide = 0;

prevBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (currentSlide > 0) {
    currentSlide = currentSlide - 1;
    slide();
  } else if (currentSlide == 0) {
    currentSlide = slidesTab.length - 1;
    slide();
  }
});

nextBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (currentSlide < slidesTab.length - 1) {
    currentSlide = currentSlide + 1;
    slide();
  } else if (currentSlide == slidesTab.length - 1) {
    currentSlide = 0;
    slide();
  }
});

function slide() {
  slidesTab[currentSlide].style.opacity = 1;
  currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % slidesTab.length;
  slidesTab[currentSlide].style.opacity = 0;
}
```

```css
.carousel {
  padding: 0;
  width: 15cm;
  height: 7cm;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto 65px auto;
  border: solid lightgray 1px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 2px lightgray;
}

.carousel-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.slide {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

.slide-1 {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/3783471/pexels-photo-3783471.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-2 {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/574069/pexels-photo-574069.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide-3 {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/701773/pexels-photo-701773.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel" class="carousel">
  <div id="previous" class="arrow">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 96 960 960" fill="white">
        <path d="m304 974-56-57 343-343-343-343 56-57 400 400-400 400Z" />
      </svg>
  </div>
  <div id="next" class="arrow">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 96 960 960" fill="white">
        <path d="m304 974-56-57 343-343-343-343 56-57 400 400-400 400Z" />
      </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-content">
    <div id="slide-1" class="slide slide-1"></div>
    <div id="slide-2" class="slide slide-2"></div>
    <div id="slide-3" class="slide slide-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

However, when I click on the back button, nothing happens. The next button, on the other hand, works perfectly fine. I've checked the console to see if there are any errors, but I haven't found anything. I've also checked that the HTML elements are correctly referenced in my code.

As a beginner, I'm stuck and I don't know what to do to solve this problem. Can you help me understand why the back button is not working and how to fix it? I'm also hoping for your indulgence as I'm still learning.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The HTML is invalid. In `<div id="slide-2" class="slide slide-2">/div>` is `/div` should be `</div>`. Is that a copying error?

Comment: I don't see the arrows in the snippet.

Comment: Changing to `fill="black"` I see a big diagonal line in the div. I think there's a problem with your SVG path.

Comment: is a copying error

Comment: The problem is the `slide()` function. It always adds 1 to `currentSlide`, regardless of which direction you're going. So the back button subtracts 1, `slide()` adds 1, so they cancel each other out.

Comment: Why does it increment `currentSlide` at all? That was already done by the event listeners.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I was a bit confused when writing my code.

Comment: What you could do is have a separate `direction` variable. The back button sets it to `-1`, the forward button sets it to `1`. Then the `slide()` function can do `currentSlide = currentSlide + direction;`

Comment: Okay, I understand. I will make the necessary changes to my code accordingly. Thank you for the suggestion!